# How can I combine the front end code in /public with back end code in /apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to rails, and created a simple bootstrap site and put it all under /public folder.

Now I wanted to make a contact form so I followed [this](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/) tutorial and made a simple rails app.

My question is, following the tutorial the contact form UI created is in /app/views, which does not have the same styling as my bootstrap UI. Is there a why for me to create a form in the /public htmls and call some of the function in the rails backend?

Comment: You have to create your form as a view in your Rails app. You don't call functions from the /public directory because you aren't supposed to be putting code in there in the first place.

Comment: I see. But in these case, wouldn't all my UI code be in two separate places? The ones that needs rails back end at one place, and the rest at another?

Comment: Nope. All your UI code should be in your views. Just ignore the /public directory for now.

Comment: In this case, when will the /public be used?

Comment: When you want to update or customize static files such as favicon.ico, robots.txt or standard error pages.